# Implementing a jslider to work with javafx and speed of movement

Tags: javafx, jslider

so i was wondering if it was possible to use jslider to say make the speed of an animation speed up or slow down. Take the following code for example.

```
cpane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> 
    {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            cpane.iSpeed();
        } else if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
            cpane.dSpeed();
        }
        });

    public void iSpeed() {
        animation.setRate(animation.getRate() + 2);
    }

    public void dSpeed() {
        animation.setRate(
                animation.getRate() > 0 ? animation.getRate() - 2 : 0);
    }
```

What i did here was make it so that my speed would slow or get faster as the left or right mouse buttons were pressed. Does anyone know how to take that an make it work with a j slider? If so would you be able to show me?

Comment: A [jslider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html) is a Swing control, you wouldn't use that in a JavaFX application, perhaps you meant a [slider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html)?

Comment: Yes i would just like to be able to get a slider in there some how im not at all really sure how to make it work like that.